# Remove leading zeros from input type=number

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, numbers

I noticed that if i use `<input type="number" />` the leading zeros are not removed. I also saw a lot of discussion on how **keeping** leading zeros.

For example "000023" and "23" are the same number and i think that it doesn't make sense keeping those zeros.

Comment: What is it you are trying to actually do?

Comment: Because i have an input that contains an amount, so is better to display it without leading zeros.

Comment: And what is the problem you face? How to remove the leading zeros or questioning whether it is sensible to leave the leading zeros in the display?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just use a regular expression like this

```
textboxText= textboxText.replace(/^0+/, '')
```

Comment: Really, a regular expression? why not something like `+'00022'.toString()`

Comment: it blocks decimal seperator

Answer (score 65):

I'm going to give an example with react usage. It uses `state` which store the value of the field. But, I think u can replace it with whatever variable you like.

`<input type='number' value={Number(this.state.myNumber).toString()}/>`

In my case, `myNumber` stores a year number. This way, the year `2018` (for example) won't be displayed mistakenly as `02018`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Also, you don't need to have the Number() part if you're doing any processing that converts it to a number. For example, in mine I am rounding the numbers so I only need `this.state.myNumber.toString()`

Comment: This will not let you input numbers like `24.036` numbers with leading zero after decimal.

Comment: This was beautiful until I had to enter 5..7.. then move cursor to the middle, then 0, in order to get 0.507, but thanks!

Comment: @RicoRodriquezCollins You can just move the cursor to the front and press `.`, it will automatically add `0.`

Answer (score 5):

HTML input tags always return text, not numbers, even its content can be coerced into numerical formats, dates, etc...

So next you should convert that input to an actual number format:

```
parseInt(myNum); // If you expect an integer.
parseFloat(myNum); // If you expect floating point number.
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of effort to get rid of leading zeros from a numeric string. Again, in both cases `+'00022'.toString()` would work

Comment: Also, it can be unsafe to use `parseInt` without supplying a `radix`

Comment: You are implicitly doing the same. "+00002" simply foreces type coercion (that is, call parseInt() in this case) and, additionally, taking more effort to convert it again to string which I figure out, in the best case, it is not intended.

Comment: Coercion does not call `parseInt`. Unlike `parseInt`, when using `+` or `Number` no `radix` is necessary because the internal number conversion will not parse octal numbers.`parseInt`: [Although discouraged by ECMAScript 3 and forbidden by ECMAScript 5, many implementations interpret a numeric string beginning with a leading 0 as octal. The following may have an octal result, or it may have a decimal result.  Always specify a radix to avoid this unreliable behavior.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)

Answer (score 1):

add step="any" to your input tag.
if this does not work on your browser, change type to type="tel"

Comment: type="tel" still allows for leading zeros, although maybe it's a useful trick to filtering for whole numbers only.

Comment: I was searching for an answer to DISPLAY leading zero's, or actually, to hold them on input while displaying the nice number input on mobile, seems `type="tel"` is the way to go!

Answer (score 1):

The hack I have used when using React is to overtly convert the number into a string.
Use `value=myNumber.toString()`, instead of `value=myNumber`.
This is only required if the the input type="number", not when if type="text"`.

If your variable is initialized to null, you can prevent errors by changing falsey values to 0, as in: `value=(myNumber || 0).toString()`.

```
class inputHours extends React.Component {

    this.state = { hours: 0};

    render() {
      return ( 
              <label>Hours: could show Leading 0's</label>
              <input  type="number" min="0" max="24"
                      value={this.state.hours}
                      onChange={this.onChangeHours}
              />

              <label>Hours: strips leading zeros</label>
              <input type="number" min="0" max="24"
                      value={this.state.hours.toString()}
                      onChange={this.onChangeHours}
              />
      );
    }
```

In the first case, even if you strip leading zeros in the `onChangeHours` handler, force conversion back to an Integer via `parseInt()`, and call `setState()` to save the number devoid of leading zeros back to the state object, telling react to re-render, the input field itself does not update to remove any leading zeros.
But this issue only arises when the input type is set to "number".
If it is set to type "text", there are no issues, leading zeros are removed as expected.
In both cases, a console.log() shows that the value stored in state is indeed stripped of leading zeros (a single 0 is allowed as a value.)
even as the input field itself may show extra leading zeros.

My best guess is that internally React sees an integer 0 === 000, so it does not bother to update the display???
But in a text string, '0' != '000', so it knows it must update the rendered field.
Anyway, the overt coersion seems to force the input field to update and re-render correctly.

Update:
@bitiset has a more complete answer that takes real numbers (floats, decimal points) into consideration.

If your numeric value will be a floating point number with a decimal, instead of an integer, consider using `parseFloat()` instead, otherwise zeros following the decimal point may get deleted, causing bugs.

However, if you overtly convert your stored value to a string before "saving" it, instead of relying on implicit coercion at read time, perhaps this issue is avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="number" id="txtfield" /><button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var myNumber = document.getElementById("txtfield").value;
    document.write(parseInt(myNumber ,10));
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this property on the input tag

```
onInput={(e) => {e.target.value = Math.abs(e.target.value);}}
```